# Solution to the Integral of the Multiplication of Two Polynomials Under the Square Root

Tags: field-theory, integration

Anybody has an idea of the generic solution of this integral?
$$
\int_0^pdx \sqrt{A+(p-x)^2}\sqrt{B+x^2}
$$
where $A,B < p$. If $A$ and $B$ is zero, we can find a definite solution. However, when they are not zero, we have the square root of a 4th power polynomial. I need a new approach for this 4th power polynomial that does not have elliptic function after the integration. [Wolfram Mathematica throws a solution with an Elliptic function, which has imaginary parts. $A$ and $B$ represent the masses of the particles that cannot be imaginary and $p$ represents the momentum of the particle.]

Comment: What's wrong with elliptic functions? Do you suspect that this can be simplified to some other expression? If it can,, a mathematical reference book chapter about elliptical functions might help.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, actually, this integral has a part of the amplitude of a decaying particle. As far as I could see, the solution with the elliptic functions always have imaginary parts. I should simplify this terms before the integration that does not lead me to the complex solution but only to real one.

Comment: Why did you post this on Physics SE rather than Math SE?

Comment: I can't see how an integral over a real function is supposed to pick up an imaginary part.

Comment: Solutions involving elliptic functions may have imaginary components when evaluated at arguments with imaginary components, while still being real at real arguments.

Comment: Are you interested in asymptotic approximations? For example, as $p \to \infty$ (or just as well, as $A, B \searrow 0$), the integral has value $\frac{1}{6} p^3 + \frac{b}{2} p \log p + \textrm{(lower-order terms that can be computed)}$.